# What is the lowest achievable Trainer level that completes the Pokédex by catching only?

Tags: pokemon-go

You earn XP (and therefore can level up) from catching Pokemon. Hypothetically, what is the lowest possible achievable level to complete the WHOLE Pokedex?  That is, without utilising any of these extra actions that award XP:

- Catch bonuses
- Excess Pokéstop Spins
- Evolving
- Gym Battles
- Done in more than one day
- Maximum balls in a spin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Pokemon GO reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/5a4u0a/lowest_level_to_have_a_complete_pokedex/) asked a similar question back when only 142 were available (before Ditto and assuming only one regional pokemon).

The minimum then was level 14 based on 142 x 600 XP = 85200.

Comment: For reference: 600XP = 100 (catch) + 500 (new Pokedex entry)